# JQuery Validation results being placed outside of the cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting the validation function results "Required field" to fill the text input box of a table.

The current code is placing the result to the right of the cell instead of inside.
I'm fairly positive it's the $(this).parent().append portion but after trying several other variations I haven't achieved the expected results.

*The code verifies that a value is currently in the cell by means of examining the class = requiredField attribute.

Any tips are much appreciated. -Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form#commentform').submit(function() {
    $('form#commentform .error').remove();
    var hasError = false;
    $('.requiredField').each(function() {
        if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">*Required field</span>');
            hasError = true;
        }
    });
    if(!hasError) {
        alert('Validation Complete');
    }
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: if parent is a TD... then code is placing span in TD. Issue doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `after()` method:

```
$(this).after('<span class="error">*Required field</span>');
```

http://api.jquery.com/after/